# Python script running successfully on command prompt but not in crontab

Tags: python, unix, cron

I have written a python script.py in my ~home/ directory which calls other python scripts located ~home/bin. 
When i run script.py i am able to run it successfully but when i schedule script.py in crontab, script.py is not able to call  script from bin directory.

Crontab script looks like this:

```
*/59 * * * * script.py &>~concatenation.log
```

script.py calls another script as following:

```
subprocess.call('/home/sdcme/bin/nii_mdir_sdcme %s %s' % (a, a), shell=True)
```

can some one point it out why script.py is not able to call the other script. I suspect the problem is with PATh variable or other such thing but dont have nay idea how i should troubleshoot this..

Thanks!

Edit: nii_mdir_sdcme script calls another script niidicom_sdcme located in the same bin directory: Crontab mail, shows following error mail -

```
niidicom_sdcme: Command not found.
niidicom_sdcme: Command not found.
```

Summary:

cronatab-> script.py -> nii_mdir_sdcme -> niidicom_sdcme
the problem is nii_mdir_sdcme is not able to call niidicom_sdcme. 
But when i run script.py independently on command prompt everything works fine..

nii_mdir_sdcme code:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
if ($#argv < 2) then
  echo "Usage: nii_mdir_sdcme start_dir# end_dir#"
  exit
else    
 set start = $argv[1]
 set end = $argv[2]

  if ( ! -d ./medata ) then
   sudo mkdir ./medata
 endif
 sudo chown sdcme ./medata
 sudo chgrp users ./medata

 set i = $start
 while ( $i <= $end )
   echo " "
   if ( $i < 10 ) then
     echo "Entering 000$i..."
     cd 000$i
     sudo chmod 777 .
     niidicom_sdcme run0$i
     #mv *+orig.* ../medata
     sudo chmod 755 .
   else
     echo "Entering 00$i..."
     cd 00$i
     sudo chmod 777 .
     niidicom_sdcme run$i
     #mv *+orig.* ../medata
     sudo chmod 755 .
   endif

   cd ..

   @ i++  
 end
```

endif

Comment: Are you certain that the cron job (script.py) is running? You may need to include the full path to that command in the crontab. Also, check the permissions of the second script. Is it executable, and is it accessible to the user that's running the cron job?

Comment: Did cron give a local email message about this? Check using `mail` or `mutt`.

Comment: @minopret i have edited my question with the mail error

Comment: Are you sure that `niidicom_sdcme` is not run? The error looks like printed by `niidicom_sdcme` itself i.e., it can't find `run0$i` or `run$i` commands (sh, bash, zsh produce different error messages here). Unrelated: `&>` looks like `bash` syntax (set SHELL explicitly in the crontab), `subprocess.call` uses `/bin/sh` if `shell=True` (you could use `executable` parameter to choose other shell), your script runs `/bin/tcsh`. Make sure there are no error due to difference in syntax between the shells.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian if subporocess.call() is calling sh screipt while my script is written in tcsh, then the wrapper python script (nii_mdir_sdcme) shoudlnt have worked when run manually.. I know i am repeating but i am still not undertsnding the problem ..

Comment: @tryeverylanguage: `subprocess.call()` does run `/bin/sh` that in turn runs `/bin/tcsh` that runs the commands specified in `nii_mdir_sdcme` file. What happens if you provide the full path to `niidicom_sdcme`?

Answer (score 3):

It probably is a problem with `$PATH`. See [`crontab(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/crontab.5.html) regarding the environment cron uses to run jobs.  One of the simplest solutions is to adjust your crontab entry to give the full path to the script:

```
59 * * * * /home/sdcme/bin/script.py &>~concatenation.log
```

Also check your email.  cron will email you the output and any failures to run the job.  If you don't have a mail server on your system you will want to install and configure one so that you get such notices.

*PS.* Using `*/59` as the minute spec is not very meaningful, so I changed it to the equivalent `59`, above.

Comment: Thank you! i have edited my question with the error shown in mail. Does that help us to gain insight whats happening with the code.

Comment: Yes: your script `nii_mdir_sdcme` expects to find `niidicom_sdcme` in $PATH, but it is not.  Maybe you want to add /home/sdcme/bin to $PATH in your crontab.

Comment: should i write $PATH = /home/sdcme/bin or PATH = /home/sdcme/bin.. Latter case is not working and i am afraid $PATH will change the original $PATH variable ..

Comment: apparently adding $PATH to crontab gives me same error

Comment: @tryeverylanguage: you should use `PATH=/home/sdcme/bin:/bin:/usr/bin` (note: no `$`)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thats not helping.. still getting the same error:

Comment: @tryeverylanguage: Do you use `env` `call()` parameter? What is `print(os.environ['PATH'])`? Do you see `/home/sdcme/bin` there? What is `ls -l /home/sdcme/bin/nii_mdir_sdcme`? Do you see executable permission for the user that runs crontab commands?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian yes i use subprocess.call. '/home/sdcme/bin' is present in os.environ['PATH']

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian also permissions looks good. crontab user has executable permission for nii_mdir_sdcme

Comment: When calling `subprocess.call()`, do you pass the absolute path to the program to execute? It needs it, because normally when something is to be executed you don't wany any search that might find the wrong thing. Alternatively subprocess.call() can be instructed to run the given command in a shell, which would then search the PATH. The "command not found" error means that what is being looked for is not found; it is different from a "permission denied" error.

Comment: @dsh with subprocess.call() i am trying to run that command in my shell window as i know my shell will be able to run it .. The whole problem is the python wrapper scipt is called manually on cmd it runs perfect ... but when cronatb calls this python wrapper which in turns call nii_mdir_sdcme is not working .. 

Python wrapper script -> nii_mdir_sdcme ->niimdir_sdcme..  niimdir_sdcme is not found .. thats the error

Answer (score 0):

first of all use crontab -e
to exit editor use :xi to save and exit
then you have to edit your line from

```
*/59 * * * * script.py &>~concatenation.log
```

to

```
*/59 * * * * /usr/bin/python script.py &>~concatenation.log
```

the /usr/bin/python is the path to your python

Hope that it works for you